# CakePHP VS CodeIgniter for a User Management Web tool

Tags: codeigniter, cakephp

I have **Core PHP** knowledge and recently i got a project **User Management Web tool**. So i am just confused which Framework should i use. I have come to know that both are best but difference in speed.

Suggestion please.

Which framework best for fast learn and in coding.

Which takes less time in development.
and also other feature

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You'll have die-hards arguing relentlessly for either side, but basically it comes down to opinion and there is essentially no right or wrong answer.

I started learning CodeIgniter because it seemed to have an easier learning curve than CakePHP. I don't remember why, but I switched to Cake years ago and haven't looked back. I've found Cake pretty easy to learn, too.

From what I've heard, the future doesn't look that bright for CodeIgniter. See articles below:

"CodeIgniter used to have a bigger community, but many moved to different frameworks after EllisLab, the company behind it, dropped support and no new features were added." - from http://phpmaster.com/goodbye-codeigniter-hello-laravel/

and also http://heybigname.com/2012/05/06/why-codeigniter-is-dead/

I'd go with CakePHP, but I'm biased, because I use CakePHP. In any case, the topic has been discussed again and again all over the web, so do a bit of research, pick a framework, and get coding! Good luck!

Comment: @joshua.paling I know it's not the place to ask questions but yes I need help in CakePHP. I am new to CakePHP and have developed application in CakePHP 3. I is working fine in localhost with PHP 7. Now I have uploaded the project on a shared host. provided all `mod_rewrite` working and php 7 I am getting `500 Internal Server error`. I followed all guides on google but never succeed. I have created question [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37928932/cakephp-3-500-internal-server-error?noredirect=1#comment63323576_37928932) Can You guide on how to properly install CakePHP on shared host?

Answer (score 6):

As joshua.paling said, it boils down to personal preference of choosing CakePHP or CodeIgniter.

I've used CodeIgniter, Kohana, FuelPHP for the past 3 years, but all my new projects are build using [Laravel](http://laravel.com/). I believe Laravel is the future of open source PHP frameworks.

Having a great documentation and plenty of high quality screen casts available, you will get started with it in no time.

Answer (score 2):

It's true what Marko Said. You will find many posts saying "Codeigniter is dead".

In case if you do move to Laravel. [This](https://tutsplus.com/course/whats-new-in-laravel-4/) will be helpful.